# Recreating iTunes library from a .itdb file?

Tags: itunes, ipod-touch, macos

My Windows laptop (and HDD) have died, taking with it iTunes and my music. Things could have been a lot worse, but I fortunately have a back up of my mp3s. However, I have lost the iTunes library containing all my play counts, last played, ratings etc.

I am keen to recover this data and have bought software to access my iPod Touch as a hard drive which has enabled me to view the underlying files. However I don't seem to be able to find a version of the `iTunes Library.itl` (or `iTunes Music Library.xml`) file which would contain the meta data I need.

The only seemingly useful file I can find is the `library.itdb` file, which seems about the right file size to contain the data I'm looking for.

My question therefore is can anyone advise if there is a way of recreating the library `.itl` or `.xml` file from this `.itdb` (iTunes database) file?

---

*NB.* I have managed to extract the meta data I need, but the program I am using creates its own paths to the `mp3` files, which would leave every track broken.

Answer (score 1):

You never said whether your hard drive is dead. If it's not, pull it out and use it as an external drive (with the help of a SATA-Firewire adapter). Use `Migration Assistant.app` to copy over your music, or just copy your iTunes folder (e.g., `"~/Music/iTunes Media/"`).

Then, the next time open up iTunes, hold down <kbd>alt</kbd> as you tell it to open. In the following dialog box, select the new location of your iTunes Media folder.

---

My apologies if your hard drive is legitimately dead. I don't yet have privileges to comment on a question, which would have been a more appropriate vector for asking you to clarify the state of your hard drive.

Comment: Thanks Merchako for a great answer, but unfortunately my hard-drive was knackered so I couldn't retrieve the data from it. I should have mentioned that in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=synchipoditunesdata

Comment: Thanks Harv - it could be what I'm looking for but I'm on Windows and that script is Mac only :o(